# Python - How do i add an existing dictionary to a set of new keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My function give me a dictionary in following format-

```
{
  "key1": {
    "deleted": [],
    "inserted": []
  },
  "key2": {
    "deleted": [
      {
        "end": 5,
        "line": "",
        "start": 5
      }
```

However, I want to have this output as below -

```
 {  "section1":
                    {
                        "name":"key1",
                        "deleted":[],
                        "inserted":[],
                    }
          },
    {  "section2":
                    {
                        "name":"key2",
                        "deleted":[],
                        "inserted":[],
                    }
          },

{  "section3":
                    {
                        "name":"key3",
                        "deleted":[],
                        "inserted":[],
                    }
          },
```

The function I have written is -

```
diff_data = {}

    with open('2018temp.json', 'w') as f1t, open('2019temp.json', 'w') as f2t:
        json.dump(f1_dict, f1t)
        json.dump(f2_dict, f2t)

    for section in settings['includes']:
        f1_text = f1_dict.get(section, [])
        f2_text = f2_dict.get(section, [])
        diffile = []
        diff = difflib.Differ()
        with open('diffile.txt', 'a') as f:
            for line in diff.compare(f1_text, f2_text):
                f.write(line + ('\n' if not line.endswith('\n') else ''))
                if line.startswith(("-", "+", "?")):
                    diffile.append(line)

        data = {'deleted': [], 'inserted': []}

        for i, line in enumerate(diffile[:-1]):
            if line.startswith('-'):
                if diffile[i+1].startswith('?'): # Deletion and modification
                    updated_line = diffile[i+2]
                    update_start = re.search('[-+^]', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    update_end = re.search('[-+^][^-+^]*$', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    data['deleted'].append({'line': diffile[i+2][2:], 'start': update_start, 'end': update_end})
                elif diffile[i+1].startswith('+') and i+2 < len(diffile) and diffile[i+2].startswith('?'):
                    pass # Addition and modification, do nothing
                else:
                    data['deleted'].append(line[2:]) # Pure deletion
            elif line.startswith('+'):
                if diffile[i+1].startswith('?'): # Addition and modification
                    update_start = re.search('[-+^]', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    update_end = re.search('[-+^][^-+^]*$', diffile[i+1]).start()
                    data['inserted'].append({'line': line[2:], 'start': update_start, 'end': update_end})
                else:
                    data['inserted'].append(line[2:]) # Pure addition

        diff_data[section] = data
```

I tried to change *diff_data[section] = data* to -

```
diff_data.setdefault('section',[]).append(data)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

    diff_data['section'].append(data)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
diff_data.append({'section': [data]})
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Any clue, how should I approach this. It seems to be a simple problem, but I am not able to get the formatting correctly as the required output. How can I write a loop to have an existing dictionary inserted as a values to new set of keys - *"section1, section2...…"*

Comment: Your desired output is confusing.  It is not a single dict with keys `section1`, `section2`, etc; it appears to be a tuple of _separate_ dictionaries.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes.. That's what is the problem, I am supposed to have the output in that format and I have a huge dictionary, hence, need a way too write a loop so that I can have the output like that.

Comment: It's confusing because _it doesn't match what you said you wanted_.  Do you want a single dict with many keys, or do you want many dicts, each with one key?  You're contradicting yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would copy the dict, put the original key as value with reference `name`, and create a new key to reference the new dict.

```
diff_data = {}
i = 1

for key, d in x.items():
    new_dict = d.copy()
    new_dict['name'] = key
    new_key = "section_{}".format(str(i))
    diff_data[new_key] = new_dict
    i += 1
```